# Show gallery images from folder into webpage using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load a gallery of images from a folder. I'm using JavaScript/jQuery. Here is the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dir = "images/"; // folder location
    var fileextension = ".jpg"; // image format
    var i = "1";

    $(function imageloop(){
        $("<img />").attr('src', dir + i + fileextension ).appendTo(".images");

        if (i==13) {
           alert('loaded');
         } else {
           i++;
           imageloop();
         };
    });   
});
```

```html
<a href="#" onload="imageloop()"></a>
```

But it shows nothing.
Please tell me what's wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: First, try to open just image url in the browser.

Comment: Add this to the `<head>`: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Provide more of your HTML - and explain what is `.images` that you're appending too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to the `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I rewrote the code since there were no specifics on the file locations try using a `while` or`for` loop.

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#btn').click(function(e) {
    var dir = "http://loremflickr.com/200/150?random=";
    var i = 0;
    e.preventDefault();
    while (i < 14) {
      $("#images").append('<img src="' + dir + i + '" />');
      i++;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="images"></div>
<button id="btn"><a href="#">LOOP</a>
</button>
```